# Stop new line in Mathematica

Tags: notebooks

I have a really long formula in Mathematica notebook. I want to display the formula as one long line. Mathematica keeps making the formula longer than one line so makes two lines. I need the formula displayed as one long line because I'm saving the document as a pdf.

Comment: does `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PageWidth -> Infinity]` give what you need?

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the expression with `Style` with the option [`LineBreakWithin-> False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineBreakWithin.html) :

```
Style[StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}], 400],
   LineBreakWithin -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can set the [`PageWidth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PageWidth.html) to `Infinity` for all cells in the current notebook:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PageWidth -> Infinity]
```

[image]