# How to draw right angled triangle with a, b and c lengths shown?

Tags: graphics, geometry

I'm trying to draw a right angled triangle with hypotenuse length 1,opposite length `b` and adjacent length `c` in Mathematica. How do I do this? I'm trying to draw an isosceles triangle showing length 1 for hypotenuse and side `a` and side `b` for other sides.

Comment: So a 45,45,90 triangle, and you want the hypotenuse labeled "1", one side labeled "b", and one side labeled "c"? Is this what you're after?

Comment: That is what I want. Please

Comment: Perhaps you want to look up `Graphics`, `Line` and `Text`. Using just these three commands you can draw all kinds of illustrations and add labels. If you already have something, just share it with us and we can help you more easily.

Comment: SSSTriangle generates lengths 3 4 5 but not 1,a, and b.

Comment: `b=.3;Graphics[SSSTriangle[1,b,Sqrt[1-b^2] ]]`?

Comment: Mathew, welcome to mma.se. If you are the same Mathew Reading who posted [Stop new line in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180782/125) you should combine your profiles so that all your posts are in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a suggestion for a function which takes arbitrary x and y lengths, and plots a right triangle with those values. Adjust the styling/options as desired.

```
plotTriangle[x_, y_] := 
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, 
   Line /@ {{{0, 0}, {x, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, y}}, {{x, 0}, {0, y}}}}, 
  Axes -> True, 
  Epilog -> {Inset[Style["a", 20, Red], {x/2, 0 + y/15}], 
    Inset[Style["b", 20, Red], {x/15, y/2}],
    Inset[Style["1", 20, Red], {x/2 + x/15, y/2 + y/15}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you prefer to use `Epilog` instead of `Text` or `Inset` in the first argument of `Graphics`?

Comment: You can use whatever you want. This is just what I chose in this instance.

Comment: I tried the code you suggested and pressed shift enter and the graph didn't show. How do I get the graph to show?

Comment: It's a function definition. Plug values into the function. Like `plotTriangle[2,2]`

Comment: Sorry I missed plotTriangle[4,5].

Answer (score 2):

You can also post-process the diagram produced by [`LaminaData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaminaData.html)`["Filled345Triangle" , "BoundaryDiagram"]` to get a diagram labeled as desired:

```
text = {"b", "c", 1};
i = 1; Replace[LaminaData["Filled345Triangle" , "BoundaryDiagram"] , 
 {p : Polygon[{{0, 0}, __}] :> {LightBlue, p}, Text[_, p_] :> Text[text[[i++]], p]}, ∞]
```

[image]