# Label position and angle-marking on right triangle

Tags: graphics, labeling

Using the advice given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180807/how-to-draw-right-angled-triangle-with-a-b-and-c-lengths-shown), I have a right triangle given by

```
plotRightTriangle[x_, y_] := 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
Triangle[{{0, 0}, {x, 0}, {x, y}}]}, 
   Epilog -> {Inset[Style["a", 15], {x/2, 1/2}], 
 Inset[Style["b", 15], {x - 1/2, y/2}], 
       Inset[Style["c", 15], {x/2 - 1/2, y/2 + 1/2}]}]

plotRightTriangle[15, 8]
```

[image]

I would like to make two changes:

1. put the labels `"a"` and `"b"` outside the triangle instead of inside (when I change the coordinates of the label, the label just disappears because outside the area of the graphic)
2. mark each angle - a small square at `ab`, and small arcs at `ac` and
   `bc`.

How do I do this?

**Addendum:**

If I have started the wrong way, please feel free to set me on a better path!

Comment: 1. Don't use Epilog but put it next to the triangle, plot range will adapt automatically then.  2. the command for a square is Rectangle and an arc is a Circle with a third parameter.
p.s. if you have v12 you can play with GeometricScene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[plotRightTriangle]
plotRightTriangle[x_, y_, r_: 2, s_: .1] := Module[{t=Triangle[{{0, 0}, {x, 0}, {x, y}}]},
  Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], t,
   Inset[Style["a", 15], {x/2, 0}, {0, 2}], 
   Inset[Style["b", 15], {x , y/2}, {-3, 0}], 
   Inset[Style["c", 15], {x/2 - 1/2, y/2 + 1/2}], 
   CapForm["Butt"], Thick, Orange, 
   RegionIntersection[t, Circle[{x, y}, r]], 
   RegionIntersection[t, Circle[{0, 0}, r]], Red, 
   Line[{{(1 - s) x, 0}, {(1 - s) x, s x}, {x, s x}}]}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]]

plotRightTriangle[15, 8]
```

[image]