# Drawing an arc inside an angle

Tags: plotting, graphics

Assuming we have two lines which define an angle

```
a10 = Graphics[{Line[{{5.9, -0.3}, {7.1, 1.3}}]}];
a11 = Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.025], Thick, Arrow[{{5.9, -0.3}, {5.9, 1.95}}]}]; 
plot = Show[{a10, a11}]
```

[image]

How can we draw a vector arc for identifying the angle? It would be nice to be able to control the size of the arc and also its relative position (how low or high from the center of the angle).

Comment: You can draw arc using `Circle[{x,y},…,{θ1,θ2}]` gives a circular or ellipse arc from angle θ1 to θ2.

Comment: @vipa I don't want just a part of circle but an arc with a vector.

Comment: You can use, as you have already done  `Arrow[curve,…]` to represents an arrow following the specified curve.

Comment: The solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10958) combined with `Arrow[]` should suit your needs.

Comment: I'm sorry but seem that `Arrow` don't work with `Circle` as curve.

Comment: see also: [How do I add arrowheads to circular arcs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13547/125)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197995/1871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have create this function:

```
angleArc[vCenter_, startPoint_, endPoint_,radius_]:=Module[{c=vCenter,p1=endPoint,p2=startPoint},
ang[center_,p_]:=If[center[[1]] < p[[1]] && center[[2]] < p[[2]], ArcTan[(p[[2]] - center[[2]])/(p[[1]]-center[[1]])],
If[center[[1]] > p[[1]] &&(center[[2]] <= p[[2]] || center[[2]] > p[[2]]), Pi + ArcTan[(p[[2]] - center[[2]])/(p[[1]] - center[[1]])],
If[center[[1]] < p[[1]] && center[[2]] < p[[2]], 2Pi + ArcTan[(p[[2]]-center[[2]])/(p[[1]] - center[[1]])],
If[center[[1]] == p[[1]] && center[[2]] < p[[2]], Pi/2, 3Pi/2]]]];
{Circle[c,radius,{ang[c,p1],ang[c,p2]}],
If[ang[c,p1] < ang[c,p2],
Arrow[{{radius Cos[ang[c,p1] + 0.01], radius Sin[ang[c,p1] + 0.01]} + c,
{radius Cos[ang[c,p1]], radius Sin[ang[c,p1]]} + c}], 
Arrow[{{radius Cos[ang[c,p1] - 0.01], radius Sin[ang[c,p1] - 0.01]} + c,
{radius Cos[ang[c,p1]], radius Sin[ang[c,p1]]} + c}]]}]
```

where *vCenter* is the coordinate of the vertex of the angle, *startPoint* is any coordinate of a point on the start side of the angle, *endPoint* is any coordinate of a point on the end side of the angle, and *radius* is the radius of the arc.

Counterclockwise arc:

```
Graphics[{Line[{{5.9, -0.3}, {7.1, 1.3}}],Line[{{5.9, -0.3}, {5.9, 1.95}}],
angleArc[{5.9, -0.3},{7.1, 1.3},{5.9, 1.95},1]}]
```

[image: CounterClockWise Arc of Angle]

Clockwise arc:

```
Graphics[{Line[{{5.9, -0.3}, {7.1, 1.3}}],Line[{{5.9, -0.3}, {5.9, 1.95}}],
angleArc[{5.9, -0.3},{5.9, 1.95},{7.1, 1.3},1]}]
```

[image: ClockWise Arc of Angle]

**Edit**

As indicated by @Cesareo in the comment below in the previous code there in same little bug. The correct one should be:

```
angleArc[vCenter_, startPoint_, endPoint_,radius_]:=Module[{c=vCenter,p1=endPoint,p2=startPoint},
ang[center_,p_]:=Which[
center[[1]] < p[[1]] && center[[2]] < p[[2]],
 ArcTan[(p[[2]] - center[[2]])/(p[[1]]-center[[1]])],
center[[1]] > p[[1]] &&(center[[2]] <= p[[2]] || center[[2]] > p[[2]]),
    Pi + ArcTan[(p[[2]] - center[[2]])/(p[[1]] - center[[1]])],
center[[1]] < p[[1]] && center[[2]] >= p[[2]],
    2Pi + ArcTan[(p[[2]]-center[[2]])/(p[[1]] - center[[1]])],
center[[1]] == p[[1]] && center[[2]] < p[[2]],
    Pi/2, 
    True, 3Pi/2];
{Circle[c,radius,{ang[c,p1],ang[c,p2]}],
If[ang[c,p1] < ang[c,p2],
Arrow[{{radius Cos[ang[c,p1] + 0.01], radius Sin[ang[c,p1] + 0.01]} + c,
{radius Cos[ang[c,p1]], radius Sin[ang[c,p1]]} + c}], 
Arrow[{{radius Cos[ang[c,p1] - 0.01], radius Sin[ang[c,p1] - 0.01]} + c,
{radius Cos[ang[c,p1]], radius Sin[ang[c,p1]]} + c}]]}]
```

Now the code work for the example in the comment:

```
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {7.1, 0}}], Line[{{0, 0}, {7.1, -4.}}], angleArc[{0, 0}, {7.1, 0}, {7.1, -4.}, 1]}]
```

[image: angle arc]

Comment: Needs correction. Try for instance 
`Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {7.1, 0}}], Line[{{0, 0}, {7.1, -4.}}], angleArc[{0, 0}, {7.1, 0}, {7.1, -4.}, 1]}]`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the GraphicsTools package from Terry Honan. The zipped package files are available [here](http://terryhonan.net/Mathematica/GraphicsToolsMechanicsTools.zip).

```
<< GraphicsTools`
```

The example from his notebooks:

```
With[{W = 50}, 
 Graphics[{Arrowheads[.1], With[{θ = Angle[{6, 4}, {1, 0}]},
           Rotate[{{CoordinateAxes[{-48, 53}, {-25, 40}, ArrowSize -> 3],
           Text["⊥", {53, -5}], 
           Text["∥", {-5, 40}],
          {AbsoluteDashing[3], 
           Line[{W {-Cos[θ], 0}, 
           W {-Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, W {0, Sin[θ]}}]},
           AngleLabel[{180 ° - θ, 180 °}, 15, 23, "θ"],
            AbsoluteThickness[2],
          {Red, LabeledArrow[W {Cos[θ], 0}, Style["N", Italic], 
           TextOffset -> -.6]},
           LabeledArrow[ {30, 5}, {30, 5 + 25}, Style["a",Italic], TextOffset ->-.6],
         {Brown, 
           LabeledArrow[{-3.5, 0}, {-3.5, 0} + .8 W {0, Sin[θ]}, 
           "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(k\)]\)", TextOffset -> .8, 
          TextPosition -> .7]},
         {Blue, 
          LabeledArrow[W {-Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, 
          Style["m g", Italic], TextOffset -> {2.9, -.6}],  
          LabeledSegment[W {0, Sin[θ]}, 
          Style["m g sinθ", Italic], TextOffset -> {.5, -1.}],          
          LabeledSegment[W {-Cos[θ], 0}, 
          Style["m g cosθ", Italic], 
          TextOffset -> 1.6]}}}, θ + 90 °, {0, 0}] /. 
          t_Text :> Rotate[t, -θ - 90 °]]
         }, BaseStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
         PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-60, 50}}]]
```

[image]

All credits should go to Terry Honan.